# How to use Numpy Tile function To get this result

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I want to broadcast the array in a give fashion.I now tile() function in numpy can be used for broadcasting i tried it but not able to generate the required output.

```
input=[ [1,2],
        [3,4],
        [4,5] ]   #shape(3X2)
numpy.tile(input,----)
out put= [ [ [1,2],
             [1,2] 
           ],
           [ [3,4],
             [3,4]
           ],
           [ [4,5],
             [4,5],
           ]
         ] #shape(3,2,2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach with `np.repeat` -

```
np.repeat(a,2,axis=0).reshape((a.shape) + (2,))
```

Another one with `np.repeat` -

```
np.repeat(a[:,None],2,axis=1) # Or use np.newaxis in place of None
```

With `np.tile` -

```
np.tile(a,2).reshape((a.shape) + (2,))
```

Comment: Thanks,This is also solution

Comment: Again Thanks.Perfect

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to stack `input` with itself and `transpose`

```
np.stack([input] * 2).transpose(1, 0, 2)

array([[[1, 2],
        [1, 2]],

       [[3, 4],
        [3, 4]],

       [[4, 5],
        [4, 5]]])
```

Comment: Or if you really have to go transpose/swapaxes way and still fulfil requirement of using `np.tile` : `np.tile(a[...,None],2).swapaxes(1,2)`.

Comment: I'm always checking `pandas` questions, I forget to check `numpy`.  Its on my list of things to do so I can continue sharpening `numpy` skills as well.  Thx for the +1